# difference between accuracy_score and jaccard_similarity_score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

What is the difference between sklearn.metrics.jaccard_similarity_score and sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score ?

1.When do we use accuracy_score ?

2.When do we use jaccard ?

3.I know the formula.Could someone explain the algorithm behind these metrics.

4.How can  I calculate jaccard on my dataframes?

`array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0],
       [2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]], dtype=int64)`

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Best practices suggest narrowing your post to a single question so that people can provide a comprehensive and useful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`accuracy_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html) is straight forward, which is one of the reasons why it is a common choice. It's the amount of correcty classified samples divided by the total, so in your case:

```
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_score, accuracy_score

print(a)
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0],
       [2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]])

accuracy_score(a[0,:], a[1,:])
# 0.25
```

Which is the same as doing:

```
(a[0,:] == a[1,:]).sum()/a.shape[1]
# 0.25
```

The `jaccard_score` is suited specially for certain problems, such as in object detection. You can get a better understanding by taking a look at [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index), which is also known as *intersection over union*, and measures the overlap of two sample sets divided by the union (sample size minus the intersection).

Note that `sklearn.metrics.jaccard_similarity_score` is deprecated, and you should probably be looking at [`sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score.html). The latter has several *averaging* modes, depending on the what you're most interested in. By default is is in `binary` which you should change since you're dealing with multiple labels.

So depending on your application you'll be more interested in one or the other. Though if you aren't sure I'd suggest you to go with the simpler, which is the accuracy score.

Comment: sorry, how i calculate intercept over union based on my dataframe?do you say i can't calculate jaccard on my dataframe?

Comment: No, that's not what I said... @dev